# Dynamically load new content using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter

I have a php file and when this page load I get data from another page by `include` after page load I have a jquery code which is load new content from another php code every 50 seconds.
here my first php page code

```
<div id="load" class="scroll-cont">
<?php include 'time_line.php'; ?>
 </div>
```

ok my jquery code

```
var autoLoad = setInterval(
function ()
{
  $('#load_post').load('last.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 40000);
```

this jquery code perfectly get data from `last.php` and loaded on `<div id="load" class="scroll-cont">` but erase all data which `<?php include 'time_line.php'; ?>` loaded before.
after every 50 seconds again erase all data which jquery loaded before.
How can possible keep old loaded data and add new content to div??
you can see this example on `Twitter` timeline when new data loaded added on old ones

Answer (score 2):

It seems `load` does not support this. But you can achieve the same by using `$.get`:

```
var autoLoad = setInterval(
function ()
{
  $.get('last.php', {}, function (res) {
    $('#load_post').append(res).fadeIn("slow");
  })
}, 40000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)** instead of `.load()` in order to load the data inside `last.php` from the server using a HTTP GET request as well as **[.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)** in the success callback to insert the return content to the end of your element:

```
var autoLoad = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $.get('last.php', function (res) {
        $('#load_post').append(res).fadeIn('slow');
    })
}, 40000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this..

```
 var autoLoad = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
      $.get('last.php', {}, function (res) {
        $('#load_post').append(res);
      })
    }, 40000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can do it by ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "your url",

        mimeType: "text/html; charset=iso-8859-2",
        data: {
            text: 4,
        },
        complete: function() {
        },
        success: function(msg) {

            $('#load_post').html(msg); 
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error in connection :(");
        }
    });
```